# polymer template auto-binding : on-core-select fires before template-bound event

Tags: javascript, events, polymer

I am using an auto-binding template, which contains some basic core elements such as core-menu and core-submenu. One of the menu elements has an on-core-select event handler defined. When the app loads, the on-core-select event fires before the template-bound event does. Is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often the case if the `on-core-select` by `core-submenu` fires before loading the rest of the page, a solution is to set an eventHandler for 'polymer-ready' event.

Polymer fires a 'polymer-ready' event when all the elements have been loaded on to the page.
So you code might look like this:

```
window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
      document.querySelector('core-submenu').addEventListener('on-core-select', doSomething());
});
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't it suppose to be _core-select_ instead of _on-core-select_? I think the _on_ is used inside the element-tag and not the script itself. Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: wirlez you are correct, you have to bind to the 'core-select' event. 'on-core-select' is use to attache the event declaratively via HTML. Also, in my case, I am attaching the 'core-select' listener in the template 'auto-bind' function. Thank you very much for your help Adi & wirlez